# Call .mix from inside of gulp task

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I'd like to gather some info about Laravel Elixir. I created a custom set of tasks in gulp like

```
gulp.task('vendor', function(){
    generateCoreScripts();
    copyFonts();
    generateCss();
    generateAdminResources();
});
```

But after all subtasks finish I'd like to use Elixir to version some of the files that were generated. But the problem is I don't have much idea how to access/fire Elixir outside of the main task(the one looking like) :

```
elixir(function(mix){});
```

The `extend` method of Elixir works only for piping. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you get this solved? I am having the issue as you...

Answer (score 1):

I m facing the same problem currently , i did however found something that works for now.

i simply included `elixir(function(mix){})` inside of a gulp task. I know it's not pretty but it did the job for me